# If specific CollectionViewCell is clicked do something

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to figure out how to program my collectionView to detect what cell is tapped and then I want to do something different for each cell using a if method.

When doing this :

```
   @objc func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

       let location = sender.location(in: self.collectionView)
       let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location)



       if let index = indexPath {
          print("Got clicked on index: \(index)!")



       }
```

My debugger says for example : Got clicked on index: [0, 3] when I click on cell number 3.
What I want to accomplish is for example if cell 3 is clicked, do something.
And different actions for all the other cells.

I tried different methods like this one for example

```
 if indexPath?.section == 3 {

            NSLog("Tapped 3")
        }
```

But with no luck.
Probably a easy way to do this, but I'm very new to programming and didn't find any help on other posts or videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don’t  need to handle click event manually . Use this function for get cell click event.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
 //print(indexPath.row) // this print 2 when you click on 3rd cell(because indexes starting from 0)

if indexPath.row == 2{
 //the action you want to do when 3rd cell click
}
 // do something you want

}
```

Comment: Ok but can you make a specific code for if 3 is clicked?